# Tesseract-ocr, can i use my own segmentaion result to replace the tesseracts'?

Tags: tesseract, image-segmentation

I find tesseract-ocr's segmentation is not good for some images.

So i do the segmentation by myself.

I have tried "setRectangle", but it will recognize character by character. And the result is worse than sending the whole image to ocr engine.

I guess tesseract's post-procesing have fix many error result with context information.
So how can i just replace all the segmentation of Tesseract?
something like set the block_list?